# Would it be possible to publish my code on an official site with a third-party library?

Tags: api, legal, delphi, third-party-libraries

I'm building a rather large and extensive wrapper in Delphi for an email system called Mandrill. There are wrappers for this API in many other languages, but not for Delphi. So, I'm hoping to produce the first full wrapper. The problem is, I'm utilizing a third-party JSON parser called superobject. I'm afraid that if I complete this wrapper, I won't be able to provide my code for Mandrill to share, because of this third-party library.

If I do complete this wrapper, is there any chance that Mandrill will be able to legally publish it on their site, based on the fact that I'm using superobject? Or would I need to parse my own JSON to be applicable?

PS - I mean this question in a general concept, not necessarily for my precise scenario, but in general, if I use a third-party library, can I legally post it with my code on another third-party's site?

Comment: A more general question would be "When can I legally post the code of my application along with all its component code". And the answer is pretty simple, all open source code with permissive Mozilla/BSD/MIT/Apache license can be freely distributed.    GPL code can be distributed unless you violate the GPL.  Non-open-source code can not.  What I don't get is, where is there a difficulty or non-obvious element here for you?  If you look in Github or Bitbucket, you'll see that this is routine for millions of composite source code repos every day. GPL combinations with non-GPL code can be tricky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that the [superobject](https://code.google.com/p/superobject/) that you're using is this one. It is distributed using the [Mozilla Public License](http://www.mozilla.org/MPL/), which permits you to use this library for free even in commercial projects.

If you make a modification to the superobject library, you must distribute that modification.

Comment: +1 I can understand the code being compiled in the product which is distributed. Just to verify though, that also applies to posting the superobject code along with my code, right? So long as I clearly make sure the end-developer knows so, and don't claim that it's my own, right?

Comment: Include the license file.

Comment: Actually funny thing is they don't have a license file in their download using the same download from your link. But I will put a link to be clear.

Comment: The only reference I see in the download is a comment at the top of the code: `Usage allowed under the restrictions of the Lesser GNU General Public License or alternatively the restrictions of the Mozilla Public License 1.1`

Comment: They probably doesn't care to much if they haven't done it properly. As long as you act in good faith (and do what you've suggested) you shouldn't have a problem.